# Lord of Ultima and Bit trip runner not available in Muon Software Centre

Tags: software-center, kubuntu, games

Most of the basic apps are found in the Muon Software Centre in Kubuntu. However, I cannot find either 'Lord of Ultima' or 'Bit trip runner', although I see them available in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

I'd like to install these games via the software centre so it gets added to the download stats for the game developers to see.

How come I can't see these in Muon Software Centre?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Muon Software Center hasn't added support for the commercial repositories that Ubuntu Software Center can access.

Due to the fact that these repositories don't contain things that are freely distributable to anyone they don't use the standard repository format that is supported by all package managers (including Muon.) Instead they have a separate mechanism that allows the contents to be searched before the repositories are added, with a mechanism for adding the repositories and taking payment.

Currently Muon Software Center doesn't support this new type of repository and so none of the apps available from these repositories can be accessed using it. At this time you will have to use Ubuntu Software Center to get access to them.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score -1):

**Lord Of Ultima** is just  *A Web Based Game* actually...you can directly install it from chrome store in your browser and then if you badly want a shortcut,chrome/chromium aloows you to do that too..

You can find **Lord Of Ultima** [Here in the chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdheeblenjmceeppomdgokgilmkonced?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to add this channelling through Ubuntu to show support for gaming in Linux

Comment: I dint get you??

Comment: The OP would like to get the software though the software centre so the software developer will get the metrics and see there is a reason to add stuff to the Ubuntu software centre. Your answer bypasses the software centre completely and then there would be no metric for the software in the software centre for the developer to look at.